# Selecting multiple rows on CheckboxTreeViewer without using the 'ctrl' button

Tags: swt, jface

I have created a [checkboxtreeviewer](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/CheckboxTreeViewer.java) using the JFace library. I have created the tree viewer as below

```java
Tree tree = new Tree(parent,SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);

CheckboxTreeViewer checkboxTreeViewer = new CheckboxTreeViewer(tree);
```

The SWT.MULTI allows me to select(highlight) multiple rows of the tree using the 'CTRL key.

Is there a way we can select multiple rows without using the ctrl key. One way i know of is using the setSelection() method, which cannot be used since that causes a flickering effect when the user goes from one row to another , the Tree.java would deselect all the existing rows and then highlight the rows that are called in the setSelection method.

I feel the code [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/win32/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Tree.java#L6705-L6710) is causing a deselect to all rows and then a select on the row selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off redrawing of the tree until you have finished setting the selection, this should reduce flickering:

```java
checkboxTreeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(false);

checkboxTreeViewer.setSelection(....);

checkboxTreeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(true);
```

Comment: The flickering is actually happening due to the code on [Tree.Java][https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/win32/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Tree.java#L6705-L6710] , which is on LBUTTONDOWN ( left mouse button down ) has a logic if it's not a SWT.MULTI tree it deselects all the other rows and sets the selection to the latest param.

Comment: There is nothing you can do about code in core SWT. I can't verify that is an issue as that is Windows SWT and the code is completely different on macOS which is what I use. You asked about setSelection in your question and I am telling you how to reduce flickering using setSelection.

Comment: Yep , that does reduce the flickering to a certain extent , but when I select a record which has parent and lots of children the flickering is still alot.